# How to schedule a BTC transation in 3 years later?

Tags: transactions

How to schedule a BTC transation? I want it to be executed like 3 years later if I would not cancel it before that time point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spendable by me or deposit to exchange after 5 years?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114901/spendable-by-me-or-deposit-to-exchange-after-5-years)

Answer (score 3):

Share a pre-signed transaction containing the appropriate nlocktime with the recipient.